# Must an Akka actor distinguish whether, when a message is passed, a returned future is expected?

Tags: akka, actor

As I understand it, an actor can be sent a message "fire and forget" style with the ! operator, or "Send-And-Receive-Future" style with the ? operator. An actor that is passed a message via ? must call a self.reply or the sender will receive a timeout exception. On the other hand, an actor that is passed a message via ! cannot have self.reply if the message is not being passed from another actor.

My question is, is the Actor supposed to know at compile time whether it will be invoked with ! or ? ??? Or if the necessity of self.reply can be determined at runtime, how can this be determined? Perhaps self.tryReply is involved, but the akka documentation seems to imply that a failed attempt to reply is an error case, whereas if the sender is not an actor, it is not really an error to fail to reply if the message is passed with !

## Edit:

Here's some code:

```
package akTest

import akka.actor.Actor

object Main1 {
  val worker = Actor.actorOf[ak].start()

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val resp = worker ? "Hi"
    resp.get
    println(resp)
  }
}

class ak extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case msg:String  => {
      val response = "Received: " + msg
      println(response)
      response
    }
  }
}
```

This gets 
`Exception in thread "main" akka.dispatch.FutureTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [4995] milliseconds`

So I add a self.reply to the actor:

```
class ak extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case msg:String  => {
      val response = "Received: " + msg
      println(response)
      self.reply(response)
      response
    }
  }
}
```

This change fixes the timeout error. But now if I have a Main2 which sends a fire and forget message:

```
object Main2 {
  val worker = Actor.actorOf[ak].start()

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val resp = worker ! "Hi"
    println(resp)
  }
}
```

, a new error is produced: `[ERROR]   [2/1/12 2:04 PM] [akka:event-driven:dispatcher:global-1] [LocalActorRef] 
   No sender in scope, can't reply.`

How can I write my actor to eliminate the coupling between its manner of response and the sender's method of invoking? I don't want to have 1 version of the actor for ! and a second version of the actor for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if senderFuture.isDefined then you have a future to reply to

Comment: I am reading all these Akka questions and they all have one thing in common: almost none of them demonstrate the solution. That's kind of the whole point of this place. [BTW, clearly the docs and examples are not clear enough.]

Comment: If you want the documentation improved you need to report what needs to be fixed on either the ML or open a ticket directly as that's our feedback channels. I don't conjure code on SO because first of all, I have no time to do so, and secondly, because it is not compiled, and may as such become stale easily.

Comment: Um, I gave a perfect example in my post a week ago Viktor: every one of the examples in the docs that uses Actors has them just do a bunch of stuff in parallel, then have a listener spit out a message to the console and terminate. Completely useless. Here's what would be useful: show me how you can send a message to an actor, have it sub the work out to other actors, then _return the result_ to the REST service so it can send it back. Look at the Spray documentation if you need further help: their first page shows exactly how this is done. Your documentation, on the other hand...

Comment: shows calling tell and then blocking, then immediately says don't do this, but the only alternatives it offers further down are composed futures, i.e. not Actor-based. Cannot for the life of me imagine what is not clear at this point.

Comment: Just registered on Assembla but it says I have to be invited to the project.

Comment: Looks like maybe I need a TypedActor as the 'doorway' to the parallel slave world. This looks promising..

Comment: It's described in the docs how to open tickets: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/project/issue-tracking.html